# Kotlin direct access to Button in android.support.v4.app.Fragment null object reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to get direct access to a button in a fragment (android.support.v4) and this is what it's throwing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at             
com.....fragments.HomeFragment._$_findCachedViewById(HomeFragment.kt)
at 
com.....fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:25)
```

This is the button I'm trying to get access to in fragment_home.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/batteryInstallationButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/battery_installation"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

This is the Kotlin code in HomeFragment.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    batteryInstallationButton?.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ehere", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return rootView
}

companion object {

    fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
        val fragment = HomeFragment()
        return fragment
    }
}

}
```

Anyone know why I can't get the direct access to the Button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have two options:

1. Access `batteryInstallationButton` from `onActivityCreated` where the view will be already inflated and it will find the button.
2. Use:

> import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.view.*

see the `.view` that I added to the synthetic and use it directly from the view that you already inflated:

```
val rootView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

rootView.batteryInstallationButton?.setOnClickListener.....
```

Please let me know if this fix your issue. Regards!